# rewrite redirect issue in debian squeeze

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, 301-redirect

My server os is debian squeeze. I have these lines to redirect non-www to www in htaccess file of my website:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

but it cause this error in firefox:

```
  The page isn't redirecting properly

  Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

  This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
cookies.
```

when I comment those lines in htaccess mysite appears but in non-www format.
I'm sure it works well before on the Ubuntu . but I don't know why it doesn't work now.
would you help me?

Answer (score 1):

It may be that because you are using a 301 redirect, you are seeing a cached result.  If you created the wrong redirect and tested it and then fixed it, you will still get the old, cached result in a browser like Firefox.  Do your testing with `curl --include http://www.example.com`.

If you still get the same problem with `curl`, the problem is quite likely in the bit that you replaced with `www.example.com`.  If those two strings aren't exactly the same, you will get a redirect loop.

It may also be worthwhile using 302 redirects until you are *sure* they are correct and only then switching to 301s.